# SPItemEventReceiver don't fire when debugging

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I can't seem to make my EventReceiver fire when debugging. I'm debugging in GAC.

I'm an no expert in sharepoint or SP Objects.

I want do something when a user change the value in the dropdownbox i have created

**Dropdownbox**

```
    [ChoiceField(Name = F.Adgang, DisplayName = "Adgang", Required = true, DefaultValue = "Alle", Choices = new string[] { "Alle", "Kun indehavere" })]
    public bool Adgang
    {
        get { return G(); }
        set { S(value); }
    }
```

**Model.cs**

```
public class Model : SPFeatureReceiver
{

    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;

        site.RootWeb.CreateContentType<CourseAndEvent>();
        site.RootWeb.CreateContentType<DanboligNewsPage>();

        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            var list = web.Lists[""];
            var e = list.EventReceivers.Add(Guid.NewGuid());

            e.Name = "test_All";
            e.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded | SPEventReceiverType.ItemDeleted | SPEventReceiverType.ItemDeleting;
            e.Assembly = typeof(NewsReceiver).Assembly.FullName;
            e.Class = typeof(NewsReceiver).FullName;
            e.SequenceNumber = 10;
            e.Update();

            list.Update();
            web.Update();
        }


    }

}
```

**NewsReceiver.cs**

```
class NewsReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);

        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
        string folderName = item["Name"].ToString();
        string folderUrl = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(SPUtility.ConcatUrls(item.Web.Url, item.ParentList.RootFolder.Url), folderName);

        SPFile file = item.File;
    }

    public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemDeleting(properties);
    }

    public override void ItemDeleted(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemDeleted(properties);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why none of the ItemEvents dont fire when I debug, ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set somewhere in your code the following line of code. It will launch the Debugger:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx)

But it will not help if you havent correctly attached the EventReceiver to the object you want. I would prefer also to check this with the [SharePoint Manager](https://spm.codeplex.com/) to see if the EventReceivers are correctly attached/registered.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are attaching your debugger to w3wp.exe.  Are you sure you have the right one?
Also, have you reviewed [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650393.aspx) about debugging event receivers? (old but relevant)

Have you ensured that your event receiver is attached to the list or the site that contains it?  See [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32091/get-list-of-event-receivers-registered-for-a-list-created-from-a-list-definition).